# How can we move column from one position to another position using Wicket Web Framework

Tags: java, html, wicket

I want to move column from one place to another using Wicket framework

You an refer follwing link for reference

The output in the code below I want exactly similar using wicket web framework [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/column-moving/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use WicketStuff InMethod Grid. It supports moving columns via dragging with the mouse.

Or you could use Wicket's DataTable component and any third party JavaScript / jQuery library that could add this functionality to HTML table element.

Or you could use plain Wicket. In this case you can use an AjaxLink, shuffle/sort the list of `IColumn`s in its `onClick()` method and finally repaint the whole DataTable, e.g. `target.add(table)`. This is the easiest but also the slowest (user experience) way.